# Readonly version of a class only for non inherent classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties

I need a protected properties version of a class. Meaning that external classes can't change the values, but the inherent class can.

Here is a sample code, as you can see, I'm using a "smelly bool solution". How should I do that in a more elegant way? I hope there are some good pattern solution to this problem.

**EDIT due to a lot of "protected set" answers:**

Doing so I'll not be able to set the class property in non inherent classes and the IsReadOnly property and value during constructor will be useless.

```
public class Foo1
{
    protected bool smellyBoolSolution = false;

    public bool IsReadOnly { get; private set; }

    private int x;

    public int X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set
        {
            CheckCanWrite();
            x = value;
        }
    }

    public Foo1(bool isReadOnly)
    {
        IsReadOnly = isReadOnly;
    }

    private void CheckCanWrite()
    {
        if (IsReadOnly && !smellyBoolSolution)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Class is read only.");
    }
}

public class Foo2 : Foo1
{
    public Foo2()
        : base(true)
    {
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        int newX = 1;
        //.... calculates new x

        //Oh, using the smelly bool solution I can change my base class properties
        base.smellyBoolSolution = true;
        base.X = newX;
        base.smellyBoolSolution = false;
    }
}

//Usage
public class Foo3
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        //Foo1 in writable version
        Foo1 f = new Foo1(false);
        f.X = 1;

        //Foo2 inherents Foo1 and only Foo2 can change X
        Foo2 f2 = new Foo2();
        f2.X = 1; //Exception here.
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Your first statement describes `private` ... why do you need more than that?

Comment: IsReadOnly  can be false, so other classes can use this object as a writable version.

Comment: Hi @Pedro77, please clarify whether you have requirements to make the accessibility of the properties to be determined at runtime. In other words, do you want classes to inherit from Foo1 and only 'blow up' during runtime when they access a readonly property. In my experience, that type of requirement is rare. I'm inclined to mark CodeCaster's answer as the appropriate one because it will cause the 'blow up' during design time (in other words, the C# compiler won't allow you to compile Foo2 if it attempts to write to the property).

Comment: You can just leave it as is, and remove the `smellyBoolSolution` variable. Then, change `private int x` to `protected int x`. Then your inheriting classes can set the *field* instead of the *property.*

Comment: @EBrown, yes, of course. Thank you. I'm felling I should delete this questions.

Comment: @Pedro77 No need, the question has an answer (which documents exactly what I said). I've upvoted you back to 0 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use protected fields to enable writing from base and inherited classes, expose a public read-only property:

```
public class A
{
    protected string FooField;
    public string Foo { get { return FooField; } }

    public A()
    {
        FooField = "A";
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B()
        : base()
    {
        FooField = "B";
    }
}
```

You can even do that using automatic properties:

```
public class A
{
    public string Foo { get; protected set; }

    public A()
    {
        Foo = "A";
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B()
        : base()
    {
        Foo = "B";
    }
}
```

See also [Restricting Accessor Accessibility (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75e8y5dd.aspx).

Comment: What if I set IsReadOnly to false? I will not be able to use the class as a writable version for non inherent class.

Comment: That contradicts with your statement that only inheriting classes should be able to write those properties. Make up your mind.

Comment: only if IsReadOnly  == true. I did.

Comment: @Pedro now it's not really clear to me what you want to accomplish. Perhaps show a few usages of your class and explain what should and shouldn't work.

Comment: Added an usage sample.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int x
int X
{
    public get { return x; }
    protected set { x = value; }
}
```

or even shorter

```
int X { public get; protected set; }
```

Those two solutions are not exactly the same, because the first one uses explicitly implemented properties and the second one automatically implemented ones.

Comment: I would not consider the two solutions you posted the same. One uses auto-implemented properties, the other has explicitly-implemented properties. Yes, in this case they may work the same, but they are not the same. You should definitely include information describing so.

Comment: @EBrown good point, I did not meant to write the xs small. Fixed it with an edit.

Comment: @TimPohlmann That does **not** fix anything, in fact it does the opposite and was **not** what I said.

Comment: @EBrown you are right, I got confused for a moment.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is violating the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and should be avoided.

By inheriting from `Foo1`, the class `Foo2` promises to adhere to the interface the super class `Foo1` exposes. I.e. methods operating on `Foo1`s don't have to care whether the received input acutally is a `Foo1` or a `Foo2`. Both types expose the same interface and thus can be operated on in a unified way.

That's why there is no elegant solution to your problem except rethinking your design.